# Using the keyboard in Mac OS's tree control

Tags: mac, keyboard, gui

On Mac, how do I use the keyboard in the tree control widget to collapse/expand folders?

[image]

Comment: I believe Space is the shortcut on other platforms...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Left/Right arrow keys usually work.

Comment: I tried and they didn't. Can you confirm they work for you?

Comment: They do for me and did for every Mac I've seen in my entire life.

Comment: They work for me too.

Comment: @cool-RR Have you got any custom application shortcuts defined? Any software or modifications that would alter keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: The biggest suspect is wxPython with which I'm creating the tree control, I'll investigate this.

Comment: Yes, it was a bug in wxWidgets.